# MARS for binary outcomes

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, binary-data, splines

Is it possible to use Multiple Adaptive Regression Splines for predicting a binary outcome?

Comment: See section 13.4. http://www.milbo.org/doc/earth-notes.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it using R's `earth` package and it worked. I used a subset of the Iris data set, choosing only two Species, and it chose all four of the predictors and 8 of 15 terms. It appears to predict reasonably.

So the answer seems to be Yes.

```
Call: earth(formula=Species~., data=a)

                    coefficients
(Intercept)            0.2649069
h(5.5-Sepal.Length)    0.5429979
h(3.2-Sepal.Width)     0.2234503
h(Petal.Length-4.6)    0.5164827
h(Petal.Length-5.3)   -0.6734858
h(5.8-Petal.Length)   -0.2360982
h(Petal.Width-1.7)     5.0733963
h(Petal.Width-1.8)    -5.1097885

Selected 8 of 15 terms, and 4 of 4 predictors
Termination condition: Reached nk 21
Importance: Petal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width
Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 7 (additive model)
GCV 0.04134384    RSS 2.987092    GRSq 0.8379156    RSq 0.8805163
```

and the data

```
> str (a)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 2.8 3.3 2.4 2.9 2.7 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.6 1 1.3 1.4 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 2 levels "versicolor","virginica": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

and the confusion matrix:

```
> table (a$Species, predict (e) > 0.5)

             FALSE TRUE
  versicolor    49    1
  virginica      2   48
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. to expand on @Wayne, From the earth package's tutorial "Notes on the earth package":

```
13.4  Can I use earth with a binary response?Yes. Typically you want to predict a probability. Usually the best way to proceed is:

(i) Convert your binary response to alogical, if it isn’t that already. To do the conversion, you can use code like this: `data$response <- data$response == "survived"`

Actually, you don’t necessarily have to do that.  Although a response of type logical is canonical in this situation, if you prefer you could also use a two-level factor or a 1s-and-0s response. Earth doesn’t mind.

(ii) Include `glm=list(family=binomial))`in your call to `earth`. This tells earth to build a model that estimates response probabilities.

See Section4.1(i) for an example, and the rest of that chapter for details
```